# RXJS - Error handling in chain of observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have just learned not to nest subscribes, so instead I am using switchMapTo as a means of starting each successive step on the completion of the previous step:

e.g.

```
    const s1$ = this.retrieveAnnualLeaveVariables();       
    const s2$ = s1$.switchMapTo(this.initialise());      
    const s3$ = s2$.switchMapTo(this.retrieveData());
    const s4$ = s3$.switchMapTo(this.accumulateAnnualLeaveRecords());
    s4$.subscribe(() => outerStream.next(someResults) ) // pass the results to the outerStream
```

**What I am unclear about now, is how to integrate error handling** in a concise manner, so that I can send an error signal to *outerStream* in the event of a problem, encountered anywhere within the chain.

I have tried attaching the following to the first

```
    .catch(e => {
        return Observable.of<any>([]);
    });
```

However:

- should I append this to every **switchMapTo**? or can I manage it in one place?
- what purpose does **return Observable.of([]);** serve - do I call the error method on my outerStream from here?
- I haven't figured out how to stop the chain of events as soon as one throws an error - how do I do that?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: I wrote an answer but I have an additional question for you. From where do you get the `someResults` and what do the functions in the `switchMapTo` operators return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should chain the operators on your observable instead of creating a new constant each time you call `switchMapTo`. Then you get this.

```
this.retrieveAnnualLeaveVariables()
    .switchMapTo(this.initialise())
    .switchMapTo(this.retrieveData())
    .switchMapTo(this.accumulateAnnualLeaveRecords())
    .subscribe(() => outerStream.next(someResults))
```

Then if you have this you can add the `catch` before the subscribe.
In the `catch` you can either return a new "fallback" value as observable, an empty observable or throw another error.

If you want to stop the chain then you should return an empty Observable via `Observable.empty()`. If you return this the Observable will complete without calling the given subscribe function.

Result:

```
this.retrieveAnnualLeaveVariables()
    .switchMapTo(this.initialise())
    .switchMapTo(this.retrieveData())
    .switchMapTo(this.accumulateAnnualLeaveRecords())
    .catch(() => Observable.empty())
    .subscribe(() => outerStream.next(someResults))
```

Comment: I have adopted your suggestion for avoiding multiple constants - thanks.

I have been testing this, and it seems to me that switchMapTo does not wait for the completion of it's predecessor, whilst switchMap does - I need the code to run a step, complete, and then move on to the next step, so I think that I will require switchMap

I have had success with the error reporting - thanks. 

Much appreciated your time to reply.